Flutter : I want local notification when firebase doucment was added
I want to push a notification when a new firebase document was added.
This collection is called Doctors.
And this is my code - I am using flutter local notification package:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  importance: Importance.high,
);

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

void main() async {

  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('quotes').snapshots().listen((snapshot) {

    String newQuote = snapshot.docs.first.data()['quote'];

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'newQuote';
      newQuote,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          icon: 'ic_launcher',
        ),
      ),
    );
  });
}

I think it works just in Android.
I get errors in flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
Future addlearning() async {
     try {
      DateTime scheduleTime = DateTime.now();
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Prescription')
       .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {

    String newQuote = snapshot.docs.first.data()['prescriptionname'];

     LocalNotificationService().scheduleNotification(
       title: 'learn',
        body: 'Teacher add $newQuote a learing book',
     scheduledNotificationDateTime: scheduleTime);
     });
    } catch (e) {
     return Future.error(e.toString());
   }
}

main() {
    addlearning();
}


What errors do you get?
